# Fetch custom post related to a User

Tags: meta-query, meta-value

I am trying to fetch custom post related to a User. I am using below code.

```
$args = array(
            'post_type'     => 'tasks',
            'meta_query'    => array(
                'relation'  => 'AND',
                array(
                    'key' => 'users',
                    'id' => $user->ID,
                    'compare' => '=',
                ),
            ),
        );

        $query = new WP_Query($args);
        $posts = $query->posts;
```

But I am not getting any output.

Comment: is that user the post author? What is the `users` post meta and what kind of value does it contain? `users` implies it contains multiple IDs, but you're looking for an exact match. Would it not have made more sense to use a taxonomy if you intended to filter/search/group tasks by users?

Comment: Thanks @TomJNowell. No, that user is not the post author. Actually I am new to WordPress development. I am not sure about your questions. Thanks.

Comment: do you know where `users` comes from? Did you build the site?

Comment: Thanks @TomJNowell. I need to make relation between `users` and `tasks`. `tasks` are custom posts. I would like to fetch which tasks are related to a user. I have `user_id`.I am new. I don't know how can I do that. Thanks.

Comment: what are `'users'` though? If a task has multiple users specified then what does `users` look like? Is it `1,2,3,4`? Are there multiple `'users'`? Is it a serialised PHP array? I understand what you want to do, but there is missing technical information, without that information it is impossible to answer this question. How is `'users'` implemented? Is `'users'` a field in a field plugin such as ACF? Without knowing what the format of the values are it's not possible to answer this question